# How to make image views in eclipse 5.1 WVGA not distorted

Tags: android, eclipse, imageview

i'm kind of a newbie when it comes to android programming. When using image views, it looks good on all screen sizes except on the 5.1 wvga screen as the image looks distorted. i Have tried so many solutions like placing the Image view in a sub relative layout rather than the original layout and also i have tried using the subclass of image view which is the SquareImageView. please i need a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you copy the same image with different resolutions for each device-resolution into the respective folders? (hdpi, ldpi, mdpi, xdpi...) As recommended in the documentation it is a good practice to use different folder as you can't be sure of the screen sizes in android.

Comment: No. i just copy the image to the hdpi folder, but i thought it automatically copies into the other folders because i could see the images in the other folders.